# Is number before a noun pronoun

Tags: pronouns, numbers

I'd like to know if a number before a noun is considered as a pronoun as well. For examples, 
"2 persons", "5 cars", and so on.

Comment: What do you mean by "as well"? Your examples contain no pronouns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In those cases, it's modifying the noun, so it's an adjective.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/two

> two adjective
>   \ˈtü  \
>   Definition of two (Entry 1 of 3)
>   1 : being one more than one in number
>   2 : being the second —used postpositively
>   section two of the instructions

Where numbers function somewhat like pronouns is where the noun omitted and the number acts as the noun. For instance, "You have 5 cars. I have 3." There, 3 functions as a pronoun by taking the place of the full phrase "3 cars".